# Calculate the average consumption

Tags: mysql

I have a table in a database:

```
consumo

pk_consumo   fk_ruta    fk_vehiculo   fecha      kms     litros    litrosx100
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1           1          1      2018-04-25    345.000   80         
   2           2          2      2018-04-26    351.000   70           
   3           3          1      2018-04-27    360.000   60           x
```

Each vehicle makes a route and in each route can make a gasoline supply.

I want to make an average of liters consumed in a route with a `SELECT`, but of the vehicle number`1`. In this case we have 3 different routes. I want to make the average consumption on route number `3`, where is the x.

How could he do it? I have tried many things but I can not get it out.

The formula that I have thought is the following:

```
((kms of rute 3 - kms of rute 1)/100) / litres of rute 3
```

The result I want is the following:

```
pk_consumo   fk_ruta    fk_vehiculo   fecha      kms     litros    litrosx100
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1           1          1      2018-04-25    345.000   80         
   2           2          2      2018-04-26    351.000   70           
   3           3          1      2018-04-27    360.000   60          4,5
```

I tried this, but I do not get it right:

```
select (((select sum(kms) from consumo where pk_consumo = 3) - (select sum(kms) from consumo where pk_consumo = (3-1)))/100)/(select sum(litros) from consumo where pk_consumo = 3) total 
from consumo 
where fk_vehiculo = 2 
group by total
```

Comment: I'm not clear what your data means is kms the distance traveled on a route or the cumulative distance traveled by a vehicle over all routes?

Comment: @P.Salmon `kms` are the kilometers in which the user refuels gasoline

Comment: Explained  how `litrosx100` is calculated? Why are you expecting to get `4.5`?

Comment: @cdaiga `4.5` is an example

Comment: A real figure would be better based on your sample data.

Comment: I'm not convinced you can do this since you don't appear able to calculate how much fuel as been used - unless the first entry of 80 ltrs was from empty to a full tank.